# Qual status HTTP devo usar para quando estiver faltando um parâmetro no POST?

Tags: http, http-status

Tenho um form que será submetido para o servidor via ajax, usando um plugin para isso. Quando o form não é preenchido corretamente (no caso quando estiver faltando um parâmetro obrigatório), quero retornar um JSON com uma mensagem de erro e um status de erro, para que no javascript, o plugin entre no callback de erro ao invés de sucesso.

Sei que deve ser um da família 4xx, mas não sei qual deles.

Não parece ser nenhum desses:

- 400 - Bad request: o request deu certo, tanto que retornei um JSON
- 404 - Not found: o recurso existe, tanto que eu posso dar POST pra ele
- 403 - Forbidden: também acho que não

Qual é o status que devo retornar?

Comment: Aqui vc tem todos os códigos, mas não acho existe um erro para isso, já que não existe uma obrigatoriedade do http q seja passado um post. Talvez vc possa adotar como padrão o 412.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: O Laravel, framework do PHP adotou o `422` por padrão, quando há algum dado inválido pela validação do requisição. Faltar o parâmetro seria equivalente a violar a validação `required`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

O `422` é o mais próximo disso (já comento mais sobre ele).

No `400`, é falado sobre "*bad syntax*", mas este não é o caso (erro de sintaxe).

No `412`, é falado sobre "*preconditions that the **requester** put on the request*", ou seja, quem contactou o servidor é que tinha uma pré-condição. Mas esse também não é o caso, porque é o servidor (e não o *requester*) quem vai fazer a validação de fato. Embora, claro, seja possível haver alguma validação também do lado do formulário/cliente.

No `422`, ele fala sobre erros de semântica. Ou seja, não tem erro de sintaxe, mas tem alguma informação faltando. Parece ser o mais conveniente.

Answer (score 16):

As opiniões são divididas. Há uma pergunta equivalente no Stack Overflow em Inglês, em que as pessoas se dividem entre os códigos 400, 412 e 422:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050518/what-http-status-response-code-should-i-use-if-the-request-is-missing-a-required

Neste caso, você teria que avaliar o contexto em que o código será retornado para decidir qual o melhor código a devolver.

Comment: Eu geralmente uso 422 Unprocessable Entity: The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.

Answer (score 8):

Muito interessante o stack apontado pelo @Cigano.

Particularmente eu apoio o uso do 400 pois o servidor estaria respondendo que recebeu uma requisição ruim do cliente.

Mas por quê uma requisição ruim?

Porque alguma coisa que ele necessita para fornecer a resposta ideal e completa estava ausente. E esse *alguma coisa* pode ser, um argumento de URL (como um token), um campo de controle normalmente armazenado num *hidden* e etc.

Comment: Ou a falta de um argumento como nome de callback, no caso do `JsonP` :)